# Binomial equality proof

Tags: calculus

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} = 2^{2n-1} $$

Now, I tried:

$$ (a+b)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{n-k} b^{k} \binom{n}{k}$$

as I used: $$ (1+1)^{2n-1}=(a+b)^{n}$$ But then I'm stuck because I'm not sure what to do with the binom itself. Or I tried using the binom identities, but I'm not too sure about that too.

Comment: Take some more seconds to type "binomial" instead of "binom". We are not in a hurry...

Comment: @JeanMarie Unnec. shortenings of words are just so annoy.

Comment: @5xum Sorry, I am not native English speaker: "unnec" is an unknown  word for me (abbreviation :)?)

Comment: Well, can anyone help? The question there where Masacroso points, doesn't help because there's no explanation about the identity I need, it's only mentioned there.

Comment: @JeanMarie Although the question above is a duplicate, I can answer your question at least. The word is unnecessary, meaning "not required". I am also not native English, but somehow, I just know.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Thanks !

Comment: @JeanMarie You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Using the binomial theorem is a good idea.

$\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} \cdot a^i\cdot b^{n-i}=(a+b)^n$

For $a=x, b=1$ and $n=2m$  we get

$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}{{2m}\choose {i}}x^{i}=(1+x)^{2m}$

Now you set $x=1$ and $x=-1$

$\sum_{i=0}^{2m} {{2m}\choose {i}}= \quad \ \ \  \ \sum_{k=0}^{m} {{2m}\choose {2k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{m} {{2m} \choose {2k-1}}=2^{2m}$

$\sum_{i=0}^{2m} {{2m}\choose {i}} (-1)^{i}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k-1}=0$

Summing up

$2\sum_{k=0}^{m} {{2m}\choose {2k}}=2^{2m}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{m} {{2m}\choose {2k}}=2^{2m-1}$

Comment: can u please elaborate what u have done in 2 lines after setting x=1 and x=-1

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. I have splitted the "i´s´" into even indices (2k) and odd  indices (2k-1),

Comment: Got it,i saw the proof of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001785/what-is-wrong-with-the-proof

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Nice that you got it.

Comment: i think the answer is not same (put n=2m in answer)

Comment: I think i know where the error is. You have to raise the summation from 1 to m(rather than 1 to 2m) when you split the i's

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. You are right thanks for the comment. Haven´t noticed it. Nice skills of observation.